# MongoDB Lifecycle event access to MongoTemplate

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to implement a versioning system for my mongodb documents with Spring Data Mongodb.  I thought i'd take advantage of the Mongo lifecycle events

[Mongo Lifecycle Events in Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events)

What I wanted to do was listen to `onBeforeSave` and fetch the pristine version of the document, and get the diff between the two.

```
@Override
public void onBeforeSave(Table table, DBObject dbo) {

    if (table.getId() != null) {
        TableChange change = new TableChange();

        Table beforeTable = mongoOperations.findById(table.getId(), Table.class);

        if (!beforeTable.getName().equals(table.getName())) {
            change.setName(table.getName());
        }

        MapDifference<String, Column> diff = Maps.difference(beforeTable.getColumns(), table.getColumns());

        logger.debug(diff.entriesInCommon().toString());
        logger.debug(diff.entriesDiffering().toString());
        logger.debug(diff.entriesOnlyOnLeft().toString());
        logger.debug(diff.entriesOnlyOnRight().toString());         

        table.addChange(change);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that i can't get a reference to mongoOperations.  It keeps creating a circular reference.  Whether i @Autowire:

### Autowire Injection

Mongo config:

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="fooConverter" />
    <property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION" />
</bean>

<bean class="com.example.listener.document.TableListener"></bean>
```

Listener:

```
public class TableListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Table> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TableListener.class);

    @Autowired MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public void onBeforeSave(Table table, DBObject dbo) {
        // .... 
    }
}
```

or use [Setter Injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-setter-injection)

### Setter Injection

Mongo config:

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="fooConverter" />
    <property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION" />
</bean>

<bean class="com.example.listener.document.TableListener">
    <property name="mongoTemplate" ref="mongoTemplate" />
</bean>
```

Listener:

```
public class TableListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Table> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TableListener.class);

    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public void setMongoTemplate(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeforeSave(Table table, DBObject dbo) {
        // .... 
    }
}
```

It makes sense to me to handle the Document versioning in the lifecycle events.  I did a similar thing with PHP/Doctrine/Mongo

[How I did it with Doctrine/PHP](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate)

In the case of Doctrine I get a reference to the Document Manager in the lifecycle callback.  Any clues how i can do this same thing with Spring Data?

Comment: Is your listener class a spring managed bean ?, I tried it with a `MongoTemplate @Autowired` reference and it worked for me

Comment: Yeah, i believe it is.  I made some edits to include how i was trying to autowire.  Does that look like how you did it?

Comment: Put here also how does your MappingMongoConverter looks like - seems that you have customized it - maybe problem lies there.

There is no problem with adding autowired injection to MongoTemplate in AbstractMongoEventListener in version 1.2.0.

Comment: @eric Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try to implement ApplicationContextAware?

Comment: Sorry missed the date :)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried, few java based configurations

1. With explicit parameter:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public static class ListenerConfiguration {

      @Bean
      public TableListener tableListener(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
          return new TableListener(mongoOperations);
      }

   }
   ```
2. With @Autowired

   ```
   @Configuration
   public static class ListenerConfiguration {

       @Bean
       public TableListener tableListener() {
           return new TableListener();
       }

   }
   ```

All of which worked perfectly.

1. One option is - you just forgotten to add

   ```
   <context:annotation-config/>
   ```

   in your xml configurations, although this would not explain setter injection failure.
2. You might have bean name overrides somewhere

And many more.

Anyway, the problem lies in how you use Spring, not in the spring configurations you provided, it's fine.